# XML with content between tags

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, sqlxml

I have SQL

```
SELECT '' AS "dfn", CCFKeyType AS "dfn/b", GroupID AS "dfn/var",  ID AS "dfn/code"
FROM (
...
) A

FOR XML PATH('')
```

AND it generates

```
<dfn>
   <b>cid</b>
   <var>0115</var>
   <code>EXS</code>
</dfn>
```

I would like to generate:

```
<dfn>
   <b>cid</b>
   (<var>0115</var>):
   <code>EXS</code>
</dfn>
```

How can text data be inseted between tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  ''     AS "dfn"    , 
        'cid'  AS "dfn/b"  ,
        '('    AS "dfn"    ,
        '0115' AS "dfn/var",
        '):'   AS "dfn"    ,
        'EXS'  AS "dfn/code"
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Output:

```
<dfn>
    <b>cid</b>
    (<var>0115</var>):
    <code>EXS</code>
</dfn>
```